# python convert float to string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to read in a csv file through Pandas.

```
pd.read_csv('zip_mapping.gz',compression='gzip' ,header=None, sep=',')
```

But somehow I read in zip as float, like

```
 0     501.0
 1    1220.0
 2    1509.0
 3    1807.0
 4    2047.0
```

as I don't know  zip is in which column before I read in the data, so I could not set dtype in pd.read_csv.

I want to change zip into  int, but due to missing values I  got " could not convert NA to int "error.

Tried

```
str(zip).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

But got  this

```
'0     501.0\n1    1220.0\n2    1509.0\n3    1807.0\n4    2047.0\nName: zip, dtype: float64'
```

Actually I want  convert zip in float into  str like
 501, 1220, 1509, 1807, 2047
then I could further padding leading zeros.

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Series.astype` method to convert float to int then to string, here I am using `df` to refer to the data frame you read in from csv and `df.zip` to refer to the *zip* column (adjust accordingly):

```
df.zip.astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(5)

#0    00501
#1    01220
#2    01509
#3    01807
#4    02047
#Name: zip, dtype: object
```

If there is NA in the column, and you want to keep them as is:

```
df['zip'] = df.zip.dropna().astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(5)
df

#     zip
#0    NaN
#1  01220
#2  01509
#3  01807
#4  02047
```

---

Another option use string formatter:

```
df.zip.apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else "{:05.0f}".format(x))

#0      NaN
#1    01220
#2    01509
#3    01807
#4    02047
#Name: zip, dtype: object
```

Comment: Just wondering why I use str(zip), still get dtype as ' float64'

Comment: still get ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

Comment: You actually get a whole string, which contains a substring `dtype: float64`, not of data type string. It's how series is presented when you convert it to a string.

Comment: Yes, you can't convert NA to integer, so what you want NA to be eventually. `00000`? or remove them?

Comment: I want to keep NA as NA.  If it is 00000 it is fine I could also later remove it.